# Don't see my app when running Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I followed the [introductory tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) on creating my first android app. However, when I run the emulator I don't see my app icon anywhere so I can't test it.

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.me.learning">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.me.learning.MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.me.learning.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.me.learning.MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.me.learning.MyActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I see the icons here:
[image]

Here is the console output for the AVD:

`Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555`

Console for the app:

`03/10 16:18:36: Launching app`

So both the avd and the app seem to load okay, but I don't see app anywhere in the emulator. What am I missing?

Here is the screen:
[image]

Here is the main home screen:
[image]

The app doesn't show up.

Comment: Have you tried it over real device?

Comment: i have the same problem 
 and i faced the iusse

Answer (score 1):

When you click **Run** (The little green arrow in the toolbar at the top, or keyboard shortcut: `SHIFT+F10`), you should be presented with a dialog box that asks you WHAT device you wanna run your app on. It won't ask you WHAT you want to run, if that was your concern.

From that dialog, just select **Launch emulator** and click **OK**.

Comment: I believe OP means the emulator starts, but the app doesn't load. If you hit the green arrow, the app should start automatically when your emulator is fully booted. Maybe you made an error somewhere in your code, are you getting an error in Android Studio?

Comment: Yeah, I get that dialog box, and I select the particular device to do the emulation on (Nexus 6 API 23). The emulator boots up and I can mess around in it, but I don't see my app anywhere.

Comment: @Timmiej93 I do not think I have any errors. Android Studio doesn't show anything in red.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `Android Monitor` open, with the `logcat` tab selected?

Comment: Run it again. On the first time you start the emulator, it just 'boots up' the system on the emulator etc. Also you should see the icon in menu and it should be default android logo.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well! Here's the way I fixed it:

1. Run the emulator
2. Without closing the emulator, get to this screen and click on the button in the top left that looks like a returning green arrow coming out of a gray box. It should be above the stop button (red square).
   [bottom left of android studio, click on run the the very bottom left and then click one of the little android logos to the left of the emulator run tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzsga.png)
3. Select the running emulator in the pop up window

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same issue and i found that i had some red color underlined errors that are not compatible , i removed them and ran it once again,it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just met the same problem. I thought you should figure out all the red highlighted problems showed in the message window.

Then it will work.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Run the apk file to install directly, drag the file from a folder in your pc to the emulator